# Большая, пятидесятилитровая канистра (запятая нужна?)

Tags: пунктуация

А если:

Большая, пятидесятилитровая, новая канистра. (нужны?)

Большая, пятидесятилитровая, алюминиевая канистра. (нужны?)

Answer (score 1):

Запятые нужны:

Большая, пятидесятилитровая, новая канистра.

Большая, пятидесятилитровая, алюминиевая канистра.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Прилагательные "большая, пятидесятилитровая" в любом случае соединяют уточняюще-пояснительные отношения, так как признак назван (большая), а затем уточнен (пятидесятилитровая). Из этого следует, что "пятидесятилитровая" обособляется запятыми.

Поэтому становится неважным, какие отношения связывают остальные прилагательные, так как знаки препинания уже не меняются.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, лучше бы привести всю фразу, но я бы не считал определения однородными.
*Большая и пятидесятилитровая*? Вряд ли.